# how to get auto-populate fields in servicenow

Tags: servicenow

I have a requirement that user details should be **auto-populate** from *user table*.

In the incident form when we select a user; contact details and roles assigned to the user have to be shown in next to the fields.

```
function onChange(control, oldValue, newValue, isLoading) {
    userObject = g_form.getReference('user_field');

    g_form.setValue('u_user', userObject.user);
    g_form.setValue('u_last_name', userObject.last_name);
    g_form.setValue('u_whatever', userObject.field_on_sys_user); 
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you correctly you want to display more Information about the Caller in the Incident Form is that right?
If so you have a few possibilities:

- Since Caller is a reference field you can just put the fields on the form via form designer and make them read-only with a UI-Policy.
- On every Reference field you have a reference icon, you get a preview when you hover over that icon. You could use this functionality to display the additional fields.
- You could write a UI-Macro that displays the additional fields.

Or you create custom fields on the Incident and populate them like you are doing in your snippet, but than I would ask what exactly is your Question?